# Elegant way to do series expansion around x+$\epsilon$

Tags: symbolic, series-expansion

Suppose I have a function $p(x+\epsilon,y-\epsilon,t)$, and I want to expand it around $(x,y)$ like
$$
p(x+\epsilon,y-\epsilon,t)=p(x,y,t)+\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial x}\epsilon+\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial y}(-\epsilon)+\cdots
$$

A naive way to do it is

```
Series[p[x+e,y-e,t],{x+e,x,1},{y-e,y,1}]
```

which will result in the following error message:

```
General::ivar: "e+x is not a valid variable."
....
```

Right now I do the expansion in the following clumsy way:

```
Replace[
Normal@Series[p[x, y, t], {x, a, 1}, {y, b, 1}], 
{x - a -> \[Epsilon], y - b -> -\[Epsilon]}, 
Infinity] 
/. {a -> x, b -> y}
```

**Question**: Is there an elegant way to do it? In the end, I want to expand $p(x,y,t)$ in
$$
-(x+z)p(x,y,t)+(x+\epsilon)p(x+\epsilon,y-\epsilon,t)+(1-x-y+\epsilon)p(x,y-\epsilon,t)
$$
and keep only the $\epsilon$ terms.

Comment: What's wrong with `Series[p[x+e,y-e,t],{e,0,1},{e,0,1}]` or `Series[p[xx,yy,t],{xx,x,1},{yy,y,1}]`?

Comment: @sebhofer,Actually `Series[p[x+e,y-e,t],{e,0,1},{e,0,1}]` is what I wanted.

Comment: Ups, I just realized this should have been `Series[p[x+ex,y-ey,t],{ex,0,1},{ey,0,1}]` or just `Series[p[x+e,y-e,t],{e,0,1}]`

Comment: @sebhofer Don't forget to post this as an answer.

Comment: @Pickett If I'm honest, I wasn't (and still not am) really sure if this question would survive, as this is a pretty trivial use of `Series`

Comment: @sebhofer I see what you mean but even so your comment is not just a pointer, it is an answer, and [should be posted as such](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/90/731) just in case the question survives. The question currently has 0 close votes so I think there's a good chance.

Comment: @Pickett Oh well, you convinced me...

Comment: This gives the requested result: `Series[p[x+e,y-e,t],{e,0,1}]`. There is no need to repeat the `e` expansion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your specific needs the straightforward way to do this is

```
Series[p[x+e,y-e,t],{e,0,1}]
```

or

```
Series[p[x+ex,y-ey,t],{ex,0,1},{ey,0,1}]
```

If you want to extract the terms proportional to $\epsilon$ you can get the correct coefficients with

```
SeriesCoefficient[p[x + e, y - e, t], {e, 0, 1}]
```

or if that suits you better with

```
CoefficientList[Series[p[x + e, y - e, t], {e, 0, 1}], e][[2]]
```